# Not Able to delete a record

Tags: android, sqlite

My Function For Delete Record:

```
public void delete_byID(int uid){
    sqLiteDatabase.delete(KK_AIRLINEBOOK, KEY_ID + "= ?", new String[] {String.valueOf(uid)});       
}
```

And my code where I'm trying to delete a record:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

// set title
alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Cancel Booking");

// set dialog message
alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Do You Really Want To Cancel Your Booking!")
.setCancelable(false)
.setPositiveButton("Yes",
new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {


        // if this button is clicked, close
        // current activity
        Toast.makeText(CancelCabBooking.this, "Your
        Booking Is Canceled Now Thank You!!!!!",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        int uid=myPrefs.getInt("USERID", 0);
        mySQLiteAdapter.delete_byID(uid);
        Intent submit= new Intent(CancelCabBooking.this,Customerhome.class);
        startActivity(submit);
        finish();
        srno.setText("");
        charges.setText("");
        seats.setText("");
        CancelCabBooking.this.finish();

    }

}
)
.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

        // if this button is clicked, just close
        // the dialog box and do nothing
        dialog.cancel();            
    }

}
);

// create alert dialog
AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

// show it
alertDialog.show();

}
```

I'm not getting any error but record is not deleted. It remains as it is.
Please help me I've already referred many answers, but still not done with this.
Thank You

Comment: What is the uid that you pass in? Log the value to see if it is the right one.

Comment: also `delete()` returns int which shows how many rows where effected. You should check if he returns > 0

Answer (score 1):

You are converting the ID value into a string.
There is no record whose ID is a string with that value.

Plain integers have no problems with formatting or SQL injection, so it is safe to embed them directly into the query string:

```
sqLiteDatabase.delete(KK_AIRLINEBOOK, KEY_ID + " = " + uid);
```